# Pass two parameters from view to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET MVC4 view engine razor.

I like to pass two parameters (object, string) from view to controller.
In the view, i have this:

```
var persona = {};
        function ModeloPersona() {
            persona.CI = $('#CI').val();
            persona.Nombre = $('#Nombre').val();
            persona.Apellidop = $('#Apellidop').val();
            persona.Apellidom = $('#Apellidom').val();
            persona.Direccion = $('#Direccion').val();
            persona.Sexo = $('#Sexo').val();
            persona.Cumple = $('#Cumple').val();
        }

        function Grabar(modo) {
            ModeloPersona();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Grabar", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 
                   Persona: JSON.stringify(persona),
                   Modo: modo 
                },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function () {

                }
            });
        }
```

and my controller I have this:

```
public ActionResult Grabar(Persona mPersona, string modo){
   if (ModelState.IsValid){
     if (modo == "2"){

     }
     else{

     }
   }
   return View();
}
```

the problem is the following, the object ***mPersona*** is null but value of ***modo*** is correct.

Why mPersona is null? what is the problem, please help me with this

Regards
Ricardo

Comment: Out of interest what does *modo* equalling *2* represent? Perhaps you could be more explicit by having two *Actions*, one for each *modo*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the name of the parameter to `persona` should work:

```
public ActionResult Grabar(Persona persona, string modo){
```

The names of the parameters to the action method have to match the names of the objects in the JSON data for the model binding to work.

Answer (score 1):

see the `post` params you are sending using the ajax

```
data: { 
        Persona: JSON.stringify(persona),
        Modo: modo 
      }
```

MVC's default model binding follows the convention that is based on the parameter names, if you want the default model binder to work you have to specify the identical sending and receiving parameters in your case the receiving params in the `ActionResult` should look like

```
public ActionResult Grabar(Persona Persona, string Modo){...}
```